# Is there a simple rule of thumb for time when pressure cooking?

Tags: equipment, cooking-time, pressure-cooker

Pressure cooking reduces the time of cooking, but I want to know if there is a simple rule to follow. Let's say that I find a recipe that says that something should boil for one hour when boiling it the regular way, can I from this draw the conclusion that it is enough with (just picking a random number here) 20 minutes? Is the relation linear? Does it depend on what you're cooking?

Answer (score 2):

As found on [Chowhound](https://www.chowhound.com/post/pressure-cooker-cooking-times-876117):

> some "rule of thumb" are available but there are always exceptions!
>   As usual things at high pressure cook three times faster - 
>   The thing is, that the rules aren't always cut and dry. Chickpeas, for example, cook 90% faster in the pressure cooker (13 minutes instead of 2-3 hours). Your chicken stock, only 30-45 minutes at high pressure!
>   These "rules" should be a starting point for figuring out the cooking time.
>   Your main resource should be your own cooker's manual. It should include a good list of cooking times as they relate to your pressure cooker. The online chart that smtucker linked to is culled from pressure cooker manufacturer instructions books. There are other, more reliable versions online that have been updated with first-hand experience.
>   For example, the chart in the link lists asparagus thick and thin pressure cooking time as the same - actually, you should ONLY pressure cook thick asparagus lest your expensive purchase of thin asparagus turn into soggy mush - a reputable timing chart will make this distinction.
>   the given link can help you alot...
>   http://www.hippressurecooking.com/p/p...

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from https://www.chowhound.com/post/pressure-cooker-cooking-times-876117. You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on any Stack Exchange site. Remember to always add prominent attribution when using other sources. Thanks!